# Show MAX value with a join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max

I'm struggling a little with a query I'm trying to build. For a game I want to display the top 10 of scores.

My table looks like this:

player = id, playername, username
score = id, track, car, bestscore, totalscore, player_id (foreign key to player.id)

For the top10 I want to show the playername, the total score, the car and the track.

The current query I have is:

```
SELECT p.playername, MAX(s.totalscore) totalscore, s.car, s.track
FROM player p
INNER JOIN score s on p.id = s.player_id
GROUP BY p.playername
ORDER BY MAX(s.totalscore) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This seems to work fine, except for one problem. If a user has a score of 50 on track 1 with car 1, and then puts a score of 60 on track 1 with car 2, I see car 1 on the query. It does not seem to get the according car of the top score if this user.

I hope it makes sense what I just told.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
SELECT p.playername, MAX(s.totalscore) as totalscore, s.car, s.track
FROM (SELECT * FROM score ORDER BY totalscore DESC) s
INNER JOIN player p ON s.player_id = p.id 
GROUP BY p.playername
ORDER BY MAX(s.totalscore) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This query seems to do the trick. I've been trying around and the result-set is exactly what I mean. Is it any good though? I'm not good at SQL and just because it works doesn't always mean it's good, does it?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean. I am very new to SQL to please in normal language.

Comment: And you're new to google too?

Comment: No need to be a dick. I'm not sure what to search for because I'm not familiar with this, and my search terms are a little vague. Hence this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a non-aggregated field as part of an aggregated query that isn't in your group by, and has a many to one relationship with the relation on which you are grouping, MySQL gives no guarantee what it will return.

This query would throw an error in another RDBMS. If you care about the top score by (person,car) tuple, just add it to the group by. However, if you want each player to have a max score, regardless of what car was used, you'll need a subquery or a self join.

One way to do it:

```
SELECT p.playername, s1.totalscore , s1.car, s1.track
FROM player p
INNER JOIN 
score s1 on p.id = s1.player_id
WHERE s1.totalscore = ( SELECT MAX(totalscore) FROM score s2 WHERE s2.player_id=s1.player_id)
ORDER BY s1.totalscore DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: That seems to be the problem I have now when I add car to the GROUP BY. Could you help me with the sub query? I'm very new to queries.

Comment: Thanks about the edit. However when I try to run that I get this error: #1054 - Unknown column 's1.total_score' in 'where clause'

Comment: should be totalscore- the name of your column. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: @Bose321, did that solve your issue? If so, please consider upvoting or accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You use "Group By" on playername so the other columns will group in "what mysql desides" manner. If you want to get the cars you should add - group by car.

```
SELECT p.playername, MAX(s.totalscore) totalscore, s.car, s.track
FROM player p
INNER JOIN score s on p.id = s.player_id
GROUP BY p.playername, s.car //added car 
ORDER BY s.totalscore DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That seemed to have solved the problem. However: now the users show up multiple times when they have multiple scores. Any way to only show the highest score of a user?